# Can't add user to google group using Cloud Identity API

Tags: python, google-groups, google-cloud-identity

For some reason I'm not able to add certain users(emails) to google groups using the Cloud Identity API. More specifically, if the email is from a very well known domain, like Gmail, I'm always able to add a user, but when the email is from a not so well known domain, the API returns an error:

`'Error(2028): Permission denied for resource groups/ (or it may not exist).'`

Is there a way to workaround this issue?

I'm using Python in my project.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.